# Report Exception with Spring MVC 2.5 , JasperReport 5.5 , Ireport 5.5 , Tomcat 6

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I have successfully make a spring MVC 2.5 application based on this sample : [Spring Web MVC - Spring Web Flow Working With JasperReports](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-web-mvc-spring-web-flow)

But when i tried to access a pdf view of a report built with IREPORT 5.5 i have this exception :

```
Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbamsusers': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph

type Rapport d'exception

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbamsusers': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l'a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbamsusers': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
cause mère

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbamsusers': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.initFactory(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.loadView(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:186)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:159)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1205)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
cause mère

java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2063)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1241)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1995)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.readObject(JRBaseStyle.java:1429)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:733)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:192)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.loadReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:516)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.loadReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.initApplicationContext(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:327)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:69)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:70)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:350)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1329)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.initFactory(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.loadView(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:186)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:159)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1205)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note La trace complète de la cause mère de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de Apache Tomcat/6.0.36.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
```

I have not been able to solve this problem for a week. Please help me.

Comment: You have an issue with bean initialization. Can you provide the war file?

Comment: Hi Vitaliy Pro, thx for your reply! i have post  the war file on dropbox the link is : https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3ykhq5fp5ny0c1/mbams.war?dl=0  thanks!

Comment: I have checked the war. I don't know a cause of issue. 
But I think spring can't create  mbamsusers bean instance of org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView because /WEB-INF/reports/SpringJasperReportsspring.jasper file is incorrect or not correspond to version of jasper reports library. 
Or may be spring-webmvc.jar is not correspond to jasper reports library. 
You have 4 versions of jasper reports in /lib dir: 
jasperreports-2.0.3.jar,
jasperreports-3.5.3.jar,
jasperreports-5.5.0.jar,
jasperreports-5.6.1.jar.
I think you need one jasper reports library jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.
You're right, but I only add a single version of jasperreport in the classpath.

To solve the problem I copy all required libraries from the ireport installation folder to the lib folder and the error disappeared.

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
commons-digester-1.7.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.3.jar
hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar
iText-2.1.7.jar
jasperreports-4.0.1.jar
jasperreports-chart-themes-4.0.1.jar
jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar
jasperreports-fonts-4.0.1.jar
```